# How to call a function depending on the user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

I am trying to get a user input and then store it in a list

now what I want to do is, call a specific function depending on the [i] th value in that list

for example

`my_list[0]` has value `'a'` then I want to call the `function_a()` which i have already defined

`my_list[1]` has value `'b'` stored at that index then i want to call `function_b` again function_b has already been defined

so basically,

I want to see if the value in that list matches any of my function then I want to trigger that function

example in detail:

```
user_input : 'text'

list = []

for i in user_input:
    list.append[i]
```

so my list becomes `['t','e','x','t']`

now,

I have specific functions for each of these alphabets

(i think i should have a dictionary or something where keys are alphabets and values are respective function, I don't know if thats even phaaaasssibbble)

but i want to call those function as per these values in the list

so here i want my program to call

```
function_t
function_e
function_x
function_t
```

Comment: That is of course doable, but is smells funny. Are you sure you really have to have a separate function for each character and cannot possibly have just one function which takes the character as argument?

Comment: Hi @zvone There is a special function for each alphabet, which is unique to that particular alphabet :D

Comment: BTW, you don't need a loop to make a list of chars from a string. Just pass the string to the list constructor, eg `list('text')`. But generally there's no need to make a list if you just want to loop over the chars because you can do stuff like `for c in some_text: func_dict[c]()`

Comment: @PM2Ring Sorry replying late. Thanks for your reply, and yes both of your suggestions are quicker ways of doing what I want to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty simple example. You can make a map with letters as keys and the `function object` as values. I.E. you don't want to call the function already in the map. Only call it when the user invokes it.

```
def a_func():
    print("calling a_func")

def b_func():
    print("calling b_func")

def c_func():
    print("calling c_func")

func_map = {'a': a_func, 'b':b_func, 'c':c_func}

while True:
    func_input = input("Enter a letter 'a' through 'c'!\n")

    if func_input.strip() == 'exit':
        print('goodbye! ')
        exit()

    if func_input.strip() in func_map.keys():
        func_map[func_input]()
    else:
        print("Sorry no function for that!")
```

Here's the output:

```
Enter a letter 'a' through 'c'!
a
calling a_func
Enter a letter 'a' through 'c'!
b
calling b_func
Enter a letter 'a' through 'c'!
c
calling c_func
Enter a letter 'a' through 'c'!
d
Sorry no function for that!
Enter a letter 'a' through 'c'!
exit
goodbye!
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use dict like this:

```
>>> def func_t():
...     return "I am T"
...
>>> def func_e():
...    return "I am E"
...
>>> def func_x():
...    return "I am X"
...
>>> my_dict = {'t':func_t(), 'e':func_e(), 'x':func_x()}
>>>
>>>
>>> my_dict.get('x')
'I am X'
```

Comment: I have created the dictionary already, just like you have mentioned. The thing is, when I am running the program, all the functions mentioned in the dictionary are getting executed (I am not calling any function, I am just running the program, and all those functions are getting automatically executed)

Comment: Yeah you can just have a map of the letters as keys and the `function object` as the value

Comment: This is incorrect. It executes each function at the time when the dictionary is created, not when a character is encountered. It should be `{'t':func_t, 'e':func_e...}` and then `my_dict['x']()`